# How to turn a .txt file with a comments list back into a Word document?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

Somehow, a Word document that I saved turned into a .txt file (even if I had accidentally saved it as .txt, shouldn't that have created a copy and not deleted the original?), which means that all of its tracked changes disappeared and all of the comments were converted into a list at the end of the document. I suspect that I can recover the tracking with "compare document," but is there any way to reverse this process in  such a fashion that the comment list is automatically translated back into comments, without having to rewrite each one manually?

Comment: Unpopular question?

Comment: Plaintext has no formatting. It's gone. You cannot covert that *back* into a previously-formatted Word document. If the original file isn't on your drive, then check your backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yes, but the Word document has a signposts of the sort [AUTHOR NUMBER] inserted in the text file at the position of each original comment, along with a list of comments with the same markup at the end of the text document. *A* program could easily turn those comments back into Word-formatted comments: the only question is whether it exists, or whether Word itself can do it.

Comment: I think you're clutching at straws. Just get it from your backup & accept that anything you added since will have to be re-done.

Comment: @Tetsujin - If you think the answer to the question is that Word can convert comments to markers in a text file and an ordered list, but neither it nor any available program has the reverse functionality built-in, please feel free to write that as an answer.

Comment: Or, alternately, perhaps you could explain how to use a [library like python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/93) to read the list of comments and markers in the text file and insert them programmatically.

Comment: This is what likely happened: you generated a list of comments and saved it to the .docx file. This overwrites the file and all history is gone. Only remedy, restore from backups.

Comment: @LPChip - All the content of the file was still there. The list of comments was at the end.

Comment: Reading between the lines of this desperate flailing in hope of salvation… your next task today is to set up a proper backup routine.

Comment: I made the assumption based on the general rule that no-one still runs after a bus once they've caught it.

Comment: Yes, if you perform this action, you get a textfile with the content and comments at the end, but as its normally a .txt file, you lose all formatting etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin - As a side note, while you've been spending your time thinking about the impossibility of accomplishing what the question asked, I have been learning how to use bayoo-docx and python-docx to programmatically add comments to a .docx file, which I just did. Now it is just a matter of writing a program to recognize the comment markers in the .docx file and inserting the appropriate line from the .txt file in the general vicinity as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If a Word document has been  incorrectly saved in such a manner as to convert it to a text file with a list of comments at the end, the comments can easily be recovered by using the packages python-docx and bayoo-docx, which allow one to programmatically manipulate .docx files using Python. The latter package may be necessary to manipulate comments. This will not restore formatting or lost changes, although the latter can be recovered using Word's comparison tool if an unmodified copy of the document is available.

The following simple program can accomplish the task of restoring comments. It requires two files: a .txt file that contains the document text and a comment list at the end, which is the file that should have been generated by saving the Word document incorrectly, as well as a file containing only the text, without the comments. This file can easily be created manually (or programatically). See the code comments for a detailed description of how the code works.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from docx import Document 
import re

#Open the text file with the comments at the end

a = [] 
with open("TEXT_DOCUMENT.txt") as f:
        for lines in f:
             if re.search("AUTHOR_INITIALS", lines):
                #Remove the initial comment marker, of the form [AUTHOR_INITIALS NUMBER]
                lines = re.sub(r'\[AUTHOR_INITIALS.+\]', '', lines) #Replace AUTHOR_INITIALS with the actual initials included in the file. 
                #Then add them to an array. 
                a.append(lines)

#Assuming that the author's name does not appear in the text itself, approximately the first half of occurrences of the author's name will be the locations of the comments, 
#not the comment text itself, so we exclude them. 

a = a[int(len(a)/2-2):]
    
                                                  

#Open a document consisting of the contents of the text file with the comments removed. This is easily done manually. 

document = Document("FILE_WITHOUT_COMMENTS.docx") 
i = 0 

for para in document.paragraphs:
    #Find the location of the comment markers in the body of the text, excluding any portion of the comment list that might accidentally have been included. 

    if "AUTHOR_INITIALS" in para.text and i<=len(a):
        
        #As before, strip the comment marker.
        new_para = re.sub(r'\[AUTHOR_INITIALS.+\]', '', para.text)
        para.text = new_para
        
        para.add_comment(str(a[i]), author = 'AUTHOR', initials = 'AUTHOR_INITIALS')
        
        i = i + 1
    
        
 
document.save("OUTPUT_FILE.docx)
```

The code was written for Python 3.7, and works with Microsoft Word version 2107, python-docx version 0.2.17, and re version 2.2.1.